# How to spend money from a Goal in Mint.com?

Tags: budget, mint.com

I have been using Mint.com to budget for a few months & am trying to figure out how to use the "Goals" feature correctly. When you finish saving for a goal, how can you tell the app/website that you want to spend the money from that goal?

For example, let's say we save $50 per month in a "Car Repairs" Goal. Then, if we have a car repair that costs several hundred dollars, I want to use the money that I saved in that Goal. How can I link the transaction to the Goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recently stopped using Mint, but from what I remember [goals are tied to accounts](https://blog.mint.com/goals/how-to-use-mints-goals-06302010/) and you cannot directly categorize transactions. You will have to have a separate checking/savings account and then pay from that account for Mint to recognize the transaction. Note that when you spend from the account Mint will subtract the amount from your goal progress, which may not be what you want.

An arguably better way to do this is to have a budget category for "Car Repairs" and check the "carry remaining balance forward". You can then contribute a fix amount each month. When you don't have an expense, the remaining money carries forward to the next month. Then, any car repair transactions you can categorize as normal.

Comment: "goals are tied to accounts and you cannot directly categorize transaction" This is why I switched to YNAB, it's been loads better for categorizing transactions and recognizing spending behavior

Comment: @IsaacCorbrey I also switched to YNAB after using Mint for a couple years. It has made things much easier!

Comment: Absolutely! I recently found out that I'll be getting more scholarships for my last year of college than I need, and YNAB is the only thing standing in the way of me spending my money on frivolous things rather than, oh I don't know, saving up for a house